# How to delete duplicated elements in XML file

Tags: python, xml, duplicates, lxml, xml.etree

Here is my XML file: it contains a duplicated element `<houseNum>0</houseNum>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfHouse>
<XmlForm>
<houseNum>0</houseNum>
 <plan1> 
  <coord>
    <X> 1.2  </X>
    <Y> 2.1  </Y>
    <Z> 3.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
  </color>
 </plan1>
 <plan2>
  <coord>  
    <X> 21.2  </X>
    <Y> 22.1  </Y>
    <Z> 31.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
</color>
 </plan2> 
</XmlForm>
<XmlForm>
<houseNum>0</houseNum>
 <plan1> 
  <coord>
    <X> 1.2  </X>
    <Y> 2.1  </Y>
    <Z> 3.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
  </color>
 </plan1>
 <plan2>
  <coord>  
    <X> 21.2  </X>
    <Y> 22.1  </Y>
    <Z> 31.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
</color>
 </plan2> 
</XmlForm>

<XmlForm>
<houseNum>1</houseNum>
 <plan1> 
  <coord>
    <X> 11.2  </X>
    <Y> 12.1  </Y>
    <Z> 13.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 255   </G>
    <B> 0   </B>
  </color>
 </plan1>
 <plan2>
  <coord>  
    <X> 211.2  </X>
    <Y> 212.1  </Y>
    <Z> 311.0  </Z>
  </coord>
  <color> 
    <R> 255 </R>
    <G> 0   </G>
    <B> 255   </B>
</color>
 </plan2> 
</XmlForm>
</ArrayOfHouse>
```

**In my case, there are two type of duplications:**

*1) If the duplicated elements are successive, here is my code to remove the duplicated element, I just compare the element[i] and element[i+1], if these elemet[i].text==element[i+1].text, I delete  element[i+1]*

```
from lxml import etree
def Remove_Duplication_XML(xml_file):
    base_name = os.path.basename(xml_file)
    start_time = time.time()
    tree = etree.parse(xml_file)

    # remove duplicate skeletons
    root = tree.getroot()
    elementlist = [e for e in root.iter('houseNum')]
    numframes=[x.text for x in elementlist]
    print(numframes)
    for index_element in range(1, len(elementlist)):

        try:
            if elementlist[index_element].text == elementlist[index_element - 1].text:
                elementlist[index_element].getparent().remove(elementlist[index_element])
                print(elementlist[index_element].text)

        except:
            print(' except  ')

    # String xml without duplication
    file = etree.tostring(root).decode("utf-8")
    print(file)
```

*2) If the duplicated elements are not successive, I am looking for a line of work to do it. Any help ?*

Comment: So, if the _xml_ doc would have another `<XmlForm><houseNum>0...` node at the end, you'd like it removed as well, right?

Comment: Create a set to hold the house numbers; iterate through the  `<houseNum>` elements, inspect the number for each; if it isn't in the set add it to the set and keep the element; if it is already in the set discard it.

Comment: @CristiFati, yes what exactly I need

Comment: The code (_FrameNum_) doesn't match the _xml_. As a general practice (most likely applies to `etree` as well), removing elements from container while iterating it is a bad idea. Btw are you using `xml.etree.ElementTree` or `lxml.etree`?

Comment: @CristiFati, Sorry, just change FrameNum with houseNum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files (analoguous to using SQL, also special-purpose, to query databases). And because you already use Python's `lxml` you can seamlessly run such a script without a single `for` loop or `if` logic to remove duplicates *anywhere* in the document.

Specifically, run the [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), an XSLT 1.0 method, to index your XML document by the *houseNum* using `<xsl:key>` and then return distinct groupings. With an added bonus, below XSLT even removes the white spaces in text nodes with pretty print indentation:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="id" match="XmlForm" use="houseNum" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="XmlForm[generate-id() != generate-id(key('id', houseNum))]"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import os
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
xml = et.parse('Source.xml')
xsl = et.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM SOURCE
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(xml)

# PRINT RESULT TO SCREEN
print(result)

# SAVE RESULT TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**Output** *(notice text values are trimmed of empty space)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfHouse>
  <XmlForm>
    <houseNum>0</houseNum>
    <plan1>
      <coord>
        <X>1.2</X>
        <Y>2.1</Y>
        <Z>3.0</Z>
      </coord>
      <color>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>0</G>
        <B>0</B>
      </color>
    </plan1>
    <plan2>
      <coord>
        <X>21.2</X>
        <Y>22.1</Y>
        <Z>31.0</Z>
      </coord>
      <color>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>0</G>
        <B>0</B>
      </color>
    </plan2>
  </XmlForm>
  <XmlForm>
    <houseNum>1</houseNum>
    <plan1>
      <coord>
        <X>11.2</X>
        <Y>12.1</Y>
        <Z>13.0</Z>
      </coord>
      <color>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>255</G>
        <B>0</B>
      </color>
    </plan1>
    <plan2>
      <coord>
        <X>211.2</X>
        <Y>212.1</Y>
        <Z>311.0</Z>
      </coord>
      <color>
        <R>255</R>
        <G>0</G>
        <B>255</B>
      </color>
    </plan2>
  </XmlForm>
</ArrayOfHouse>
```